# Laravel 404 Error with parameter but without parameter it is working

Tags: laravel, eloquent, routes, laravel-8, named-routing

Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () {
Route::get('/editcategory/{$id}', [CategoryContoller::class, 'edit'])->whereNumber('id')->name('editcategory');
});

This Code gives me a 404 Not Found. But without parameter page is showing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you most remove "$" from route

```
Route::get('/editcategory/{id}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `$` in the parameter.

```
Route::prefix('admin')->group(function () { 
    Route::get('/editcategory/{id}', 
         [CategoryContoller::class, 'edit'])
                    ->whereNumber('id')->name('editcategory'); 
});
```